# Development of Rails with github after deployment on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, github, assets

I have a Rails 3.2.3 app that I host on `github` .Today I deployed it on Heroku.

During deployment, I made some changes to the `Gemfile`.

- Run `rake assets:precompile` which generate a /public/assets folder.
- I had to add and commit those change to local repository in order to 
  push to heroku by running `git push heroku master`

The deoployment was fine but now my development environment is like:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
```

Those are the changes I made for deployment on heroku (run precompile and some other stuffs) that I don't want to exist on my `github` repo. How do I do to continue my development (be able to push on `github`) and keep updating the change on `heroku`) ?

Clarification: `public/assets` is generated and should be added to local repo in order to push to heroku. So I can't put it in .gitignore But I don't want it to be pushed on github. What is the best practice?

Comment: Since `public/assets` is generated, maybe it should be added to .gitignore?

Comment: I clarify it above. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're running `rake assets:precompile` in development.  Are you debugging something?  In general, it's best not to commit compiled assets to your repo since they are generated content.

On Heroku, you have the option to precompile your assets during slug compilation.  This makes for a cleaner repo albeit a *slightly* slower deploy.  Just remove `public/assets` so Heroku knows what to do.  Also, make sure you add the following line to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar

Comment: Yes I have that already. The reason I ran rake assets:precompile is because of this site: http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html. It recomment to run precompile before deploy on heroku rather than leave that to heroku.